# Mage Resque - Job Class not found error

Tags: magento, php-resque

I'm trying to implement a asynchronous functionality in Magento using Mage-Resque. I have followed the instructions in https://github.com/ajbonner/mage-resque and installed all the components except ext-pcntl.

Now i'm able to queue a job to redis-server. I have tested the it using the default Mns_Resque_Model_Job_Logmessage class but i'm also getting following error.

```
[info] [11:09:42 2016-03-27] Checking default for jobs
[info] [11:09:42 2016-03-27] Found job on default
[notice] [11:09:42 2016-03-27] Starting work on (Job{default} | ID: 6fe2a430c10ff2920c3f66ec7d52e957 | Mns_Resque_Model_Job_Logmessage | [{"message":"Resque Test 1459057136"}])
[info] [11:09:42 2016-03-27] Forked 3759 at 2016-03-27 11:09:42
[info] [11:09:42 2016-03-27] Processing default since 2016-03-27 11:09:42
[critical] [11:09:42 2016-03-27] (Job{default} | ID: 6fe2a430c10ff2920c3f66ec7d52e957 | Mns_Resque_Model_Job_Logmessage | [{"message":"Resque Test 1459057136"}]) has failed Could not find job class Mns_Resque_Model_Job_Logmessage.
```

Its reporting that it cannot find a class Mns_Resque_Model_Job_Logmessage. What could be wrong ? Have i missed something? Please help any help would be appreciated...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: I have already posted a question and there is no response yet.

Comment: You should read [ask] and [mcve]. Those should help you to get a better response.